# League of Legends bug - can only move towards the nexus

Tags: league-of-legends

Basically, every time I click to move (or use another key I've bound to move) I head towards the enemy nexus, via the mid lane. This makes the game unplayable. Has this happened to anyone else, and if so, how do I stop it?

Comment: I strongly recommend you post this in League of Legends' forum.

Comment: Are you playing Veigar perchance?

Comment: @zpletan Yes, I am.

Comment: I don't know a fix but if you throw Veigar into your searches you may get better results. Other people have been reporting this too.

Comment: @Fabián I don't have much experience with that having any effect. I naively reported bugs on the forums, they are still on the release branch.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Bug that has been reported several times in the League forums. Some of the players claim it's a hack although it is most likely related to some form of connectivity issue.

While I haven't experienced the bug myself, closing and reopening the game seems to solve the problem for all players.

One player got a response to the bug and posted a screenshot of the ticket on [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05P55.jpg).